# HTML: Modify checkbox/radio style with CSS only

Tags: html, forms, css, input

I know this kind of question was asked at least 100 times but here is what I mean by **CSS only**:

I want to change style of checkbox/radio with CSS without beeing required to change markup of those elements ( putting them in container / adding label element etc ). I'm asking if it's possible to style `<input type"checkbox"/>` without adding any new html to it.

Such CSS could be added to any exisitng page and work. All solutions I've found requires some given type of markup and if you'd just add them to some page with forms it just will not work as they might not have labels or containers for inputs itself.

By modify I mean - changing style of box (main css like border-radius, colors, borders, shadows) and changing style of check (color, shape etc).

I know required markup can be added by JS - but it's not solution, it's workaround and I'm not looking for that.

Comment: If don't want to add additional markup, or use JS, then your best option is to use `background-images` - which will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

it is not cross-browser solution

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
    width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  -moz-appearance: none; 
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -ms-appearance: none; 
   -o-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
    outline: none;    
}
input[type=checkbox]:after {    
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;   
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;    
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;    
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked:after{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Working only on webkit based I think (ok in Chrome/Safari). Not working in Firefox - it only changes input size. (I bet it will not work in IE too)